# CI/CD or Release Management - More that one artifact for one release

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management, azure-artifacts

I am trying to find the most correct and simplest deployment process for each application release we have. The difficulties are the following:

1. It is Azure DevOps Releases.
2. Application has more than one artifact that should be delivered as a whole. Application distro, Its modules, and some configuration for servers that are not directly linked with the application, and of course automation scripts (which is versioned). All of them have their own build process and can be versioned separately.
3. All those components (App, separate server config, automation) are delivered as one product version. However, they could have different versions, for example: 12.2.1 (app), 12.2.3 (server), 12.2.1 (automation).

The question is how to build the process when after release (official), we can stick all of the final versions together (i mean not specifying them manually during pipeline release creation for each) taking into account that one of the component's version can be increased and we should be able to increase the version for release in terms of hotfixes for example.

1. Release Pipelines and 3 Artifacts: ok, there are 3 artifacts and a user has to specify all 3 versions manually during creation - quite a high risk to misclick. Unfortunately, there are 10 of them... 10 multiply 3 = 30 times to do a mistake.
2. Release Pipeline and 1 Artifact (app): Consider only one version of the application and automatically obtain automation scripts and configuration from feed by using app version. Could work, but no observability on what artifacts are going to be used, no way to downgrade, the only the latest version of artifacts (12.2.3.*).
3. Specify the version in the variable group connected to the stage (environments). Can easily make a mistake because release uses the baken version of the variable group. If you update VG, but not create a release - it will be epic fail. Moreover, there is no vision of what it is going to install/update, etc.

Please, share your ideas on how to manage multiple artifact versions within one product release to make the process more robust and clear with a little of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works for me via this simple approach:-

- A single build pipeline with many Agent Jobs where each one represents an artifact.

  - So here you will publish the different artifacts under separate folders and automatically increase versions "If needed", using a script per each and at the end all will be under the same BuildId.
  - Another variety if separation isn't needed that all be under the same Agent Job.
- A single release pipeline that is linked to this big nested artifact that will perform the deploy.

  - Here also if separation is needed, could have multi stages or multi Agent Jobs as before.
- Versions increasing either will happen manually at commits or scripts will automatically increase each build.

  - I would prefer the first as the 2nd doesn't indicate that there was any change.
  - The possibility of developer forgetting to update the version will be the same as developer introduces a bug so that can be fixed later.

Then at the end, you have a Single Release => Single Build => Many versions => A commit.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will try to put those ideas together in order to apply them to my configuration.

Comment: If it works for you later, mark the answer accepted ;)

Comment: Of course, as soon as I try to apply this to the current approach at least conceptually.